# When I select dropdown, Overlap selected blue bg on arrow in IE9 & IE8

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have used background image for select tag, When I select dropdown that time overlap selected blue color on image in IE.

Please see this link you will see my problem http://media300.dropshots.com/photos/1103166/20130528/085932.jpg

This i want, when option selected that time selected background color none. It is working properly Chrome, Firefox & safari. only got problem in IE. I used following code for this

```
.selectbox {
    width: 240px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #c2d6ea;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    background: url(../images/select.jpg) no-repeat center right;
}

.selectbox select {
    -webkit-user-modify: policy;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 0;
    color: #003399;
    width: 268px;
    padding: 7px 3px;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these lines to your `selectbox`

```
.selectbox{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```